# Cómo listar archivos en Linux sin importar mayúsculas y minúsculas

Tags: linux

Tengo un directorio en Linux llamado 'MiDirectorio' con archivos llamados:

```
ARCHIVOCLIENTE_20240301.xslx
archivocliente_20240302.xslx
ArCHivoCliEnTE_20240303.xslx
```

¿Cómo hago para listar archivos en **Linux** por coincidencia: `ARCHIVOCLIENTE_`, sin tener en cuenta las mayúsculas y minúsculas?

Estaba intentando lo siguiente: `ls MiDirectorio/archivocliente_*` pero no sé si aplique en todos los casos.

Comment: ls **-i** MiDirectorio/archivocliente_*, tienes que investigar en internet antes de preguntar aca

Comment: @Jimmy ¿estás confundiendo `ls` con `grep`? [`-i` no hace lo que pensás.](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html)

Comment: ¿Qué _shell_ estás utilizando? ¿bash? ¿zsh? ¿algún otro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asumiendo que usas bash como shell, en principio `ls` no te listara todos los archivos. El encargado de expandir el patrón no es `ls`, es la propia shell mediante el mecanismo conocido como [*globbing*](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

Puedes modificar el patrón como muestra la [respuesta de Stefan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/615703/15089) (el único problema es que es tremendamente tedioso de construir a poco que el patrón sea algo largo) o seguir usando el mismo patrón pero modificando como trabaja el globbing directamente, en bash puedes hacerlo estableciendo la opción `nocaseglob` mediante [shopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

```
$ shopt -s nocaseglob
$ ls MiDirectorio/archivocliente_*
```

luego puedes activar de nuevo la sensibilidad a mayúsculas con:

```
$ shopt -u nocaseglob
```

Si no usas bash la cosa puede cambiar, por ejemplo para **zsh** debes usar:

```
$ unsetopt CASE_GLOB
$ ls MiDirectorio/archivocliente_*
$ setopt CASE_GLOB
```

o bien usando la bandera `i` (requiere la opción `EXTENDED_GLOB`):

```
$ setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
$ ls (#i)MiDirectorio/archivocliente_*
```

Otra posibilidad podría ser usar `find` (evitando la búsqueda recursiva y limintándola a archivos) en vez de `ls`:

```
$ find ./MiDirectorio -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "archivocliente_*"
```

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla, shopt -s nocaseglob era la solución para lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza el comando ls -d de la siguiente forma:

```
ls -d MiDirectorio/[Aa][Rr][Cc][Hh][Ii][Vv][Oo][Cc][Ll][Ii][Ee][Nn][Tt][Ee]_*
```